# Compound nodes layout issues - cytoscape js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Update: Added a collage of the images I was going to add to get around reputation block

I've been working on a cytoscape implementation that will dynamically display information I'm pulling from my database onto a webpage. The goal is to be an organization chart, displaying nodes in groups, in a directed tree structure. I've been doing a lot of research, and trying out several different layouts and api options to try and meet the use case, but I'm having issues getting it to work the way I'm intending.

Specifically I want to use compound nodes - the parents being the people's ranks. I've learned that a lot of layouts simply haven't been designed with compound nodes in mind, and I've been trying different implementations, including ones that create an initial layout, and then try to run a secondary layout specifically on the descendants of the parents.

Following are the closest of what I've tried and their issues:

Images of graphs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hzVS.png

**cose-bilkent**:

The main issue with this is that it doesn't seem to be meant for directed trees, but rather decides placement on its own. The bigger issue I've had is that I couldn't find a way to spread the nodes out better within their groups. I've tried to use the node padding options included, but they haven't had an affect, which I'm assuming is due to the compound nature.

**grid:**

Graph is in a perfectly grid like layout of all the nodes, but ignores parent nodes.

This layout was working for me initially, and would have the benefit of being able to easily change the amount of people per column. As I changed the elements though I realized it was a coincidence that it worked initially - it seems like it's totally ignoring the parent nodes, which is understandable if it wasn't designed with them in mind.

**grid - descendants:**

Graph is of the two sets of descendants layered on top of each other.

What I tried next was using a different layout to determine the initial placing of the parents, and then performing a grid layout on the descendants to make them organized in their groups. I realized then that parents are simply reacting to their child's placement. Also, it appears that calling layouts on sets of nodes separately for grid was completely ignoring anything else that exists on the graph, causing the groups to be put on top of each other.

**cola:**

It's close, but the way it puts them on the graph is not well structured, causing the placement in the groups to be jumbled up, though they are spaced out enough.

This appears it would work great if I could figure out how to run a proper layout on the parent nodes, forcing the tree structure that works without compound nodes.

---

Here is more or less what I'd like to see, though the logic for # of nodes per column isn't that important. As long as they're organized neatly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/irVaK.png

Is there any advice someone could give on how I could go about making this work? I haven't been able to find any layout setups that work quite right, and I don't really know what to do from here. I would also prefer to avoid creating an entirely new layout from scratch. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, what I've done to solve this is create my own preset layout function that dictates where (children) nodes go on the graph, using their properties to dictate where they go.

It's designed to only display linear compound graphs, in order based on "level" in the hierarchy. It's capable of displaying the children nodes in grid-like sets within their parent nodes (visually - remember parents simply adjust according to their children), in the order of the mentioned linear levels.

You can also specify the values for how many columns in a set, space between nodes, and space between levels. There's obviously lots of room to make the variables more verbose if you'd like to specify "x-space" and "y-space" between nodes, and things like that.

It assumes the following:

-You know ahead of time what level corresponds to each compound group

-You know ahead of time how many nodes are in each compound group

-If you're making this dynamically, that you have a way to dynamically produce the javascript variables necessary for the dictionary, which tracks the total size of each group and how many nodes of each group have been accounted for.

Here's the code. I know it's a niche case, but if you do have a reason to use it, just keep in mind that it's sure to be bug prone, and is definitely inefficient (Javascript isn't my forte...). I've tested certain edge cases that I feel are common in my project, but there could be others that aren't accounted for.

http://jsbin.com/quyipo/edit

(Also upvotes/comments don't hurt either. I'm curious if this could actually help someone...)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a proper tree data structure, you shouldn't be using compound nodes for layout.  It's not generally possible to satisfy compound parent position restrictions when there are additional constraints on the children.  This is because a parent is naturally constrained by its children -- a parent doesn't have its own position or size, [it's children define it implicitly](http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/compound-nodes).

The best layouts for compound graphs are force-directed (physics simulation) ones like CoSE or Cola.

In your case, you just have a tree.  I would use the breadthfirst or Dagre layouts without any compounds.  Each level will naturally indicate rank.

Comment: So my other issue is that I don't want to explicitly show arrows from one person to another - in an organization that could imply that the person works directly for the person that points to them. In this case the edges simply indicate the order of the ranks in the organization. I had tried adding edges to each child and simply making them invisible, but in order to make it structured neatly it would require an exponential amount of edges from one rank to another. I'm currently working on my own 'preset' layout, with an algorithm I'm writing to manually place them on the graph.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll be sure to share the code I come up with in case it may come in handy to someone else when I finish (and I'm almost there)